# Which nested data structure should I use for posts with parents?

Tags: postgresql

I have table `Posts` with fields `id`, `author_id`, `message`, `parent_id`.
`parent_id` can be `null` or `id` of corresponding parent post.

I have also table `Votes` that contains fields `id`, `item_id` (foreign key referencing to `Posts.id`).

Which of many ways to store hierarchical data should I use for this example?

I want to return response from server similar to this:

```
[{
    user: {/* author-data */},
    text: 'some string',
    parent_id: null,
    comments: [/* list of comments, each including it's own list of votes*/],
    votes: [/* list of votes*/]
}]
```

Data will be almost never updated, quite often inserted and heavily read.

Comment: Is this some sort of RESTful API?  If so, you may want to just return URLs instead of those lists (i.e. "here's a URL where you can get the list of comments").

Comment: We target mobile users with high latency and high bandwidth, so we do not want to waste time on unnecessary requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just store it the "normal" way, using a foreign key from `parent_id` to `id`.

After that query it with a recursive query: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html

If you ever get performance issues with this, you can just add a simple caching layer.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: @Ginden: can you provide your table definition? An sqlfiddle.com could help a lot here :)